# Error building a content type in SP 2007

Tags: sharepoint, events

I have an event handler that catches an ItemAdding event and changes the content type on the fly. This is my code to build the content type:

```
SPContentType baseContentType = web.AvailableContentTypes["Folder"];
SPContentType type = new SPContentType(baseContentType, web.ContentTypes, "Custom Folder");

// Add fields to new content type
AddField(ref type, "User", "Owner");
AddField(ref type, "DateTime", "Date");
AddField(ref type, "Text", "Description");
AddField(ref type, "Text", "Justification");
AddField(ref type, "User", "Users");

list.ContentTypes.Add(type);
list.Update();
```

..snip..

```
void AddField(ref SPContentType contentType, string fieldType, string fieldName)
{
    SPField field = new SPField(contentType.Fields, fieldType, fieldName);
    if (fieldName.Equals("Users"))
        ((SPFieldUser)field).AllowMultipleValues = true;
    field.Update();
    contentType.Fields.Add(field); // Exception thrown here
    SPFieldLink fieldLink = new SPFieldLink(contentType.Fields[fieldName]);
    contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink); 
    contentType.Update();
}
```

On the line: contentType.FieldLinks.Add(fieldLink);,

I'm getting an ArgumentNullException: value cannot be null. Parameter name: g

Does anyone know what this means or can see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Stack trace:

at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.UpdateCore(Boolean bToggleSealed)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPField.Update()
at ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.AddField(SPContentType& contentType, String fieldType, String fieldName)
   at ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.ChangeContentTypeEventHandler.ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is not in your current code. It's further down the stack trace. Can you post a full stack trace?

Edit:

Okay with the full trace stack this implies that the content type is currently in use. What you need to do most likely is specify the cascading options. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms474878.aspx

such as 
    contentType.Update(true,true)

Comment: Thanks for you response.  I've added the stack trace to the original question.  I've made some changes to the code (changed the AddField method a bit) and now I'm getting an SPException on field.Update(): This functionality is unavailable for fields not associated with a list